# Qtwebkit browser has video tag and h.264 support but cannot play youtube video

Tags: flash, qt, plugins, html5-video, qtwebkit

I tried Fancy Browser Example from QtWebkit and it works fine if I enable the Plugins. The browser support video tag and h.264, but none of the youtube video can be played without flash plugins.

Since the browser potentially can play html5-video, dose anyone know why it does not work?

Thanks

Comment: And you're using Qt version...

Comment: How are you testing it, by browsing youtube.com or with embedded youtube videos? Not all youtube videos are available in H.264, and for embedded videos, it has to be the right kind of embedding (iframe instead of the older object/embed element style).

Comment: Thank you. I tested it by joining the html5 trial in  http://www.youtube.com/html5    and play a video with HTML5 video tag (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuxuK8JKfcU). But no luck~